# Why am I not able to use Vectors in the Dev C/C++ IDE

Tags: c++, vector, return, dev-c++

So, here I wanted to just define a vector and then print the size of the vector's present state, but the compiler in dev c/c++ gives me a compile-time error that "vector was not declared in the scope()"

I wonder if I haven't included the right header files,or something.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
   vector<int> v(6);               //defining the vector 
   cout<<"Size= "<<v.size();      //printing the present size of the vector
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <vector>` is the right path towards [Warp drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp_drive).

Comment: "I wonder if I haven't included the right header files" and you thought spending some minutes to ask a question here is more effective than spending some seconds to take a look at [docs of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ?

Comment: I'm new to C++, so I asked. It may appear silly, but hey, what question does not?

Answer (score 2):

Just include vector header.

`#include <vector>`